# In which layer big/little endian conversion is done?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, endianness

Suppose a packet is sent by UDP. I'm wondering in which layer the big/little endian conversion of payload is done.

Comment: Some useful topics:

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think this *is* done? The transport protocol has no notion of your data, it transmits *bytes*. You, as an application protocol designer, will have to decide and ensure to send your data in a certain endianness.

UDP doesn't know that four successive bytes somewhere in a packet form a 32-bit integer, for example. They might as well form four 1-byte values, for example UTF-8 code points. Do you want UDP to randomly invert your strings?

See also [Sending UDP packets in the correct Endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774452/sending-udp-packets-in-the-correct-endianness).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. If I use the TCP to send a stream, I don't care of byte order. Right? If it's in an application-specific structure whatever in TCP or UDP, the endianness correction has to be done in the application layer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

'Endian conversion' of a protocol is usually done in the layer that handles the protocol.

For example: NTP program/library itself creates a NTP-message in network byte order before passing the message to UDP-layer (=sending). UDP layer will create UDP header in network byte order, but does not change the payload (=NTP message).

Lower layer protocols doesn't know and care what kind of upper layer protocols are carried in the payload. There are few exceptions or borderline cases, like checksum offloading in NIC.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. If I use the TCP to send a stream, I don't care of byte order. Right? If it's in an application-specific structure whatever in TCP or UDP, the endianness correction has to be done in the application layer. Thanks.

Comment: If you send for example 32 bit integer over TCP stream by using 4 bytes, then you must take care of the byte order. If you send those 4 bytes in random order, the receiver may interpret those bytes to wrong integer value. So sender and receiver of a protocol must follow byte order rules of the protocol, or else...